# Issue encountered while VSCode plugin development

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have been following a [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) on developing a VSCode plugin using TypeScript
but I have encountered an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

I have followed the tutorial step-by-step
but when I try to run the plugin using the "Run Extension" command

[image: I found stuck in the following screen]

OS: Mac.
VScode Version

```
Version: 1.77.3 (Universal)
Commit: 704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
Date: 2023-04-12T09:19:37.325Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 21.1.0
Sandboxed: No
```

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?
Are there any additional steps that I need to take that were not covered in the tutorial?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

I already tried reopening vscode and also tried reinstalling the whole project with yo code

Comment: That `Run Extension` command you refer to is running your extension in debug mode - so of course it stops at your `debugger` line.  So just click the `Continue` icon in the Debug Toolbar popup (or hit F5 to continue).

Comment: I had try to hit F5 or Step Over or Step out
It will run one second and stop on debugger again

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the configuration for your extension it's not possible to say where the problem may lie.

An alternative approach would be to use the 'Hello World' sample in the [VSCode Extension Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples) as a starting point.

Once you've got this sample extension running properly you can then see how it's configuration is different to what you got for your first project after following the tutorial.